# Fill Spaces Between two different UIBezierpath in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I've 2 `UIBezierPath` parallel with each other. Is there anyway I could fill the space between them?

I need these *BezierPaths* separated though. I found a question like this here but the solution given doesn't suffice to my requirement. By the way, the two paths are drawn at the same time with user touch.

This is an example of the output, basically those are two points drawn at the same time, but I need the space between all the points filled in, not like that.

[image]

Comment: can you add screenshot or code?

Comment: Store starting and terminating positions of all lines. draw a line around them and fill the path drawn.

Comment: :0 Sorry I didn't understand, can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Oh... now I get it! I'll try.. thanks!!